# Is it possible to loop a vimeo video in AMP-HTML?

Tags: amp-html

The problem I have with amp-vimeo is that once the video finishes it goes onto vimeo's 3 x 3 "suggested videos".

I am trying to get it to loop to keep showing the video I want to be shown, is there a way of doing this? Or are there solutions to avoid seeing the suggested videos. Possibly an image once the video finishes?

I've tried adding in loop like amp-video documentation hoping that it may work for both with no success.

`<amp-vimeo
    data-videoid="x"
    layout="responsive"
    autoplay
    width="500" height="281">
</amp-vimeo>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon checking [`<amp-vimeo>`](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-vimeo?format=websites) component, the attribute `loop` is not supported. I would like to suggest to use [`<amp-video>`](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-video?format=websites) that has an attribute `loop`.